# Launch Screen Flow when Opportunity Sales stage changes

Tags: visualforce, lightning, visual-workflow

I'd like to know if the following is possible.  When an Opportunity reaches sales stage 3, I would like a Screen Flow to launch(which will create a Quote).

**Reason :** To create more guidance/fluency for users and reduce clicks.  Today the users have to click an Action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a Screen Flow component to the relevant Opportunity Lightning Page(s) and make the component conditionally rendered by using the "**Set Component Visibility**" option on the Lightning Page from App Builder.

See below:

[image: Setting Flow component visibility based on Opportunity Stage]

If you wanted to spice things up and make the option/prompt to create a quote more obvious by having it pop up in a modal, you could try wrapping the Flow in a Lightning component that renders conditionally on the page with this **[free Salesforce Labs AppExchange component](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMYinUAH)**.

Comment: Thanks, so you're saying I can have a lightning component render the screen flow as a pop up window?

Comment: Yes, with the installation and use of the AppExchange component I linked to above